# Añadir elemento a XML con QDom

Tags: xml, qt

Tengo el siguiente archivo XML de nombre "objectos.xml":

```
<ann>
  <object>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>20</y>
  </object>
</ann>
```

Ahora, quiero añadir un nuevo elemento "object" con el siguiente código:

```
QDomDocument doc("objectos.xml");
QDomElement ann = doc.documentElement();
QDomElement object = doc.createElement("object");
QDomElement x = doc.createElement("x");
QDomElement y= doc.createElement("y");

QDomText t_x = doc.createTextNode("30");
QDomText t_y = doc.createTextNode("40");

x.appendChild(t_x);
y.appendChild(t_y);

object.appendChild(xmin);
object.appendChild(ymin);

ann.appendChild(object);
doc.appendChild(ann);

//Escribir el documento en un archivo
QFile output("objectos.xml");
output.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
QTextStream stream(&output);
stream << doc.toString();
output.close();
```

Sin embargo, me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> "Calling appendChild() on a null node does nothing"

¿Alguien sabe como podría solucionar este problema? Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QDomDocument doc("objectos.xml");
```

Con esto *crees* que estás leyendo el XML... pero no. Para leer el XML tienes que usar un `QFile`:

```
QDomDocument doc("objectos");

// Primero leemos el XML ...
QFile file("objectos.xml");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    return; // Mostrar mensaje de error si procede
if (!doc.setContent(&file)) {
    file.close();
    return; // Mostrar mensaje de error si procede
}
file.close();

// ... y ahora ya si podemos trabajar con DOM
QDomElement ann = doc.documentElement();
// ...
```

Aunque por otro lado entiendo que la [documentación](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html#QDomDocument-2) del constructor puede llegar a ser algo confusa:

> Creates a document and sets the name of the document type to name.

Esa cadena que te pide el constructor (aunque perfectamente podrías usar el constructor por defecto), es accesible desde :

```
doc.doctype().name();
```

Y **no tiene** nada que ver con el fichero del que provenga el XML